# How to do layered resources in terraform + jenkins

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am trying to utilize jenkins jobs and tf scripts to do the following-

Job 1 - takes in a group name, runs jobs 2, 3 and 4 on 23 generated files related to that group name

Job 2 - creates variables.tf_template, variables.tf, s3_baseline, and terraform.tfstate_baseline files in a directory in S3 which is {S3_URI}/configs/{group_name}/{file_number}

Job 3 - spins up an ec2 with the name "Pipeline - {group_name} {file_number}" and runs a script on that ec2 to process the corresponding file

Job 4 - cleans up the config files and tears down the ec2 for the group name - file number pair

However, when I try to run job 2 or job 3 with the same group name but different file numbers, I am still running into the old configurations being terminated and/or used. i.e. if i try to run job 1 with group_name = example and file_number = 1, then again with group_name = example and file_number = 2, terraform still destroys the config files at example/1 instead of just creating the new ones at example/2.

Is is possible run these jobs and create unique terraform environments/configs/ec2s which don't destroy the ones generated by previous job runs, but can still be terminated on completion of the processes?

Apologies for the vagueness I'm working around some confidentiality. Can try to supply generalized snippets if needed.

Comment: I am not sure I followed your example. If you are using a single state file and run your terraform against a configuration of `example/1`, then you use the same state file but run it against a new configuration of `example/2` then terraform will say hey you have resource `example/1` in your statefile but no longer in your configuration so I will destory it for you. If that is whats happening you might want to rethink your strategy as it sounds like a nightmare

Comment: I am trying to generate two state files. - one for 1 and one for 2

Comment: Using the same configuration just different variables? have a look at terraform workspaces, they allow you to run the same config but in a seperate state file

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution - in order to isolate the state files and environments, I needed to generate new terraform workspaces for the runs